# Monitor disk I/O for specific drive in OS X

Tags: macos, hard-drive

In my Macbook Pro, I have two internal drives and I've connected a third drive via USB in enclosure.

I am currently doing a secure wipe of the external drive and I was interested in seeing what the disk I/O was for that particular drive, but when I use Activity Monitor I only see the total disk usage for all drives combined.

Is there any way to monitor a specific drive's total I/O, preferably via a built-in or free method? I don't want to filter by process ID. I just want to filter by mounted disk.

**EDIT:** It seems like for normal mounted drives, the Terminal program `iostat` should be sufficient. However, for unmounted drives (like ones which are being secure wiped in Disk Utility) iostat will not show the drive even though Activity Monitor seems to have a way to report the disk I/O for it.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the 'iostat' command.

You run the command from Terminal. Run 'man iostat' to get the manual page.

Here's a quick overview about using it with Linux.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-disk-performance-monitoring-howto.html

Comment: I had given this a try before posting my question, but it didn't work for me. I should have mentioned that.

I am able to see the external drive when I do `diskutil list` but because it is not mounted (currently not partitioned, formatted, and is being secure erased), it does not show up under `iostat`.

Comment: Ah, I see your trouble. Now I'm just speculating, but I doubt that you can monitor io without the drive mounted, or without exclusive access to the device from the monitoring tool.

Comment: I thought so as well, but when I saw that Activity Monitor was reporting the I/O speeds for what looked like the secure erase (I was not doing anything else on my main drives at that time yet the write speeds were doing about 30 MB/s), I thought it might still be possible. But, there's a good possibility that you are correct.

Comment: Doesn't work in High Sierra. Get `iostat: could not record 'disk3' for monitoring` even when run via sudo.

Comment: does work in mojave, without sudo or su

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo fs_usage -f diskio -t 1
```

may well give you a -t=1 second's worth of information.

`man fs_usage` will tell what the data columns are. With `-f diskio` option, I got these columns out:

- CALL The name of the network or filesystem related call, page-in,
  page-out, or physical disk access.
- BYTE COUNT Of the form B=x, x is the number of bytes requested by the call.
- DISK BLOCK NUMBER Of the form D=0xnnnnnnnn, where 0xnnnnnnnn is the block number of the physical disk block being read or written.
- TIME INTERVAL(W) The elapsed time spent in the system call. A ‘W’ after the elapsed time indicates the process was scheduled out during this file activity. In this case, the elapsed time includes the wait time.
- PROCESS NAME The process that made the system call. Wide mode will append the thread id to the process name (i.e Mail.nnn).

Adding up a few seconds worth of `B=` values would give you total data for that time range.

Answer (score 1):

[`iotop`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/iotop.1m.html) is a nice tool. Don't have a Mac, but works nice under Linux

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum discussion](http://ask.metafilter.com/153392/How-can-I-get-IO-stats-for-a-particular-disk-in-OS-X), GeekTool might provide the functionality that you need:

> Try [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) (tutorials from [Lifehacker tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/software/plain-text/geek-to-live--monitor-your-mac-and-more-with-geektool-244026.php) and [ThemeMyMac](http://thememymac.com/2009/applications/geektool/geektool-all-the-scripts-i-could-find-explained-for-beginners/), lots
>   of scripts at the [MacRumors forums](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?s=012a586787374f87ec27466f111dbba3&t=628023)).

I don't have access to my Mac at work, but you should be able to do some monitoring or find/create a script that does what you need with this tool.

Comment: I encountered this solution while researching too, but I searched through the thread and other sites and couldn't find any useful scripts that would be of help.

In any case, GeekTool seems to mostly support pre-existing commands that I would otherwise be able to run via the Terminal. I still haven't found a suitable command to do that. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Doesn't work in High Sierra. Get `dtrace: invalid probe specifier`.